# Driver showing up everywhere but "additional drivers"

Tags: drivers

I installed Ubuntu a month ago (dual boot w/ win10). Everything worked fine. When I replaced my GTX 960 graphics card with a GTX 1660, it disappeared from the additional drivers menu. lshw and lspci still show it correctly, and as using nvidia drivers (or noveau when I tried uninstalling them) Why is this happening? is there a way to refresh the additional drivers gui page I am unaware of? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Have you enabled proprietary drivers? This is in the same window. If so, try re-enabling them. Use `apt-get update` as root (`sudo`) after disabling, and once after enabling. If not, enable them, and `apt-get update`. Also, [this NVidia page](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/142958/en-us?ncid=afm-chs-44270&ranMID=44270&ranEAID=msYS1Nvjv4c&ranSiteID=msYS1Nvjv4c-xXrznbivzLkFQOgZZyu4Iw) might help.

Comment: Also, for future posts, please include your OS version number. (such as 19.10)

Comment: Sorry about that. version 19.10 Yes, I have tried disabling and enabling proprietary drivers, and reinstalling the driver (nvidia-driver-435). It seems to be used when I check with terminal, just not showing up in the additional drivers menu